# DBeaver ошибка Network error IOException: Network is unreachable Network is unreachable Network is unreachable

Tags: mysql, sql, dbeaver

На всех компах через тот же DBeaver работает коннект к серверу, приложения с ним работают, но на маке выдает эту ошибку при попытке подключения, притом что коннект к другим серверам на том же драйвере работает спокойно, полный вывод ошибки особо ситуацию не проясняет

[image: полный вывод ошибки]